# Generar Cabecera PDF en Thymeleaf + Flying saucer pdf + iText

Tags: java, css, pdf, thymeleaf, itext

estoy generando una funcionalidad para descargar pdf con datos a través de una plantilla HTML usando Thymeleaf 3.0, flying saucer 9.1.20 e iText 2.1.7.

La aplicación es una aplicación de microservicios usando Spring Boot y Angular.

**plantillaPDF.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>

    <style>   
    
        @page {
          @top-center {
            content: element(pageHeader);
          }
        }
        #pageHeader{
          position: running(pageHeader);
        }
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pageHeader">
       <img src="imagenes/flor.jpg" alt="logotipo" width="330" height="90" ></img>
    </div>

    <h1>TITULO</h1>
    <h2>Categoria</h2>
    <p>Fecha: <span th:text="${ fecha }">*Fecha*</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

El caso es que la plantilla si la abres en el navegador muestra correctamente la cabecera con la imagen.

[image: Imagen de la previsualización en navegador]

Pero a la hora de generar el pdf no la muestra en ninguna de las páginas que se generan:

[image: Captura del pdf generado]

En cambio, si en vez de ubicar una imagen, ubico un texto si se muestra en la cabecera de cada página dentro del documento PDF generado.

Los métodos que utilizo son:

**descargarPDF**

```
@Override
    public byte[] descargarPDF(ObjectDto dto) throws IOException, DocumentException, com.lowagie.text.DocumentException {
        
        String htmlInvoice = buildHtmlFromTemplate(dto);
        
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = this.generateDocumentBaos(htmlInvoice);
        byte[] pdfReport = bos.toByteArray();
                
        return pdfReport;       
    }
```

**buildHtmlFromTemplate**

```
private String buildHtmlFromTemplate(ObjectDto dto) {
        
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/plantillas/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        
        // Construimos el mapa de valores para generar el html de la plantilla Thymeleaf
        Map<String, Object> propertiesBody = new HashMap<>();
        propertiesBody.put("fecha", dto.getFecha());
        
        // Generamos el context y agregamos las variables al template
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(propertiesBody);
        
        return templateEngine.process("plantillaPDF", context);

    }
```

**generateDocumentBaos**

```
private ByteArrayOutputStream generateDocumentBaos(String html) throws IOException, DocumentException, com.lowagie.text.DocumentException {
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(baos, false);
    renderer.finishPDF();
    baos.close();

    return baos;

    }
```

He estado mirando y probando los ejemplos de "margin boxes and running elements" de [aquí](http://pigeonholdings.com/projects/flyingsaucer/R8/doc/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_40), pero como mencioné si solo agrego texto si se replica en la cabecera de todas las paginas pero si agrego una imagen no, y es lo que me desconcierta.

¿Alguna idea de qué es lo que esta pasando?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno despues de mucho indagar he descubierto que el problema nace de Spring Boot y su manera de extraer las rutas. Había que agregar la ruta con @classpath.

La solución fue cambiar la linea de imagen en el html por la siguiente:

`<img alt="mastercard" th:src="@{classpath:imagenes/image2.png}" />`

Ahora ya se genera la cabecera con la imagen en todas las paginas generadas dentro del PDF.